# snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: failed to add i915 component master (-19)

Tags: boot, drivers, sound

Questions:

1. What is i915 component master?
2. What is the outcome(s) of failing to add i915 component master?
3. How do I resolve/remove this failure notice?

Background Info:

This failure notice at bootup and shutdown of Ubuntu 10.5.
My built consist of ASUS Z170M-Plus mobo, NVidea graphics card Ubuntu 10.5 OS that uses Linux kernel 4.2.0-16-generic and Nvidia binary driver 352.55.

I am surprised that this failure notice appears as Ubuntu is operational and I can watch and hear videos and music.

`snd_hda_intel` appears to be an Intel audio driver in the Linux kernel that communicates with the ALSA kernel core and z170M-Plus audio hardware controller. Please correct me if I am wrong.

`0000:00:1f.3` is the PCIe slot of the built-in audio device of the ASUS mobo.

`0000:00:1f.3` ASUS Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31) is located. It uses the that is using

```
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 86c7
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 125
Memory at f7140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at f7120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: This error appeared to disappear for me after adding `nomodeset` in the grub entry and fixing bad/unused entries in my fstab, but I still have no idea what the error means

Answer (score 5):

i found this: http://www.starmate.fr/i915-component-master/ (french)

it's look like a bios option to active for Asus motherboard.

Advance -> Advance \ Systems Agent (SA) Configuration -> Configuration graphique > Multi-GPU dedicace Monitor

it's solve the problem for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

HDMI and DisplayPort display connectors can transfer audio as well as video. As you are using an NVidia GPU, the CPU's built-in Intel iGPU is probably disabled or at the very least has no displays connected to it.

The Intel chipset has a link between the audio chip and the iGPU in order to allow the iGPU's HDMI/DisplayPort display connectors to output the audio produced by the audio chip. The system firmware metadata tells the HD Audio driver to expect this link. But since the iGPU is not being used, the driver's attempt to activate this link will fail and the error message `failed to add i915 component master` will result.

The rest of the audio chip will work just fine, you just won't be getting audio over HDMI/DisplayPort connectors that are connected to the iGPU (which you probably aren't using anyway). The message would be of any significance only if you're trying to use the iGPU in addition to the NVidia GPU in a multi-display set-up, *and* want to output audio over HDMI or DisplayPort to the speakers of a display that is connected to the iGPU.

Your NVidia GPU probably has a *second* HD-Audio sound chip integrated with it, which will output audio on HDMI/DisplayPort connectors attached to the NVidia GPU. If you're using Pulseaudio on top of the usual ALSA audio drivers, it can handle this pretty much transparently so you can mix and match audio outputs as you like. If you are using plain ALSA audio drivers and want to output audio over HDMI or DisplayPort, you will need to tell the audio-producing software to use the second HD-Audio chip instead of the default one.

If you're interested, the function that outputs this message is `snd_hdac_i915_init() in file .../sound/hda/hdac_i9i5.c` within the Linux kernel source code package.

Comment: Thanks for the rich technical details.

Answer (score 1):

Setting **IGPU Multi-Monitor** to **Enabled** in the Graphics section of my BIOS settings fixed it for me.

The cause of this is the NVidia custom driver. It conflicts somehow with the video card integrated on my Motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, I recently encountered and solved a similar issue while trying to get HDMI audio to work with the built-in video ports on an Intel Z370-based system (AsRock Z370M-ITX/ac motherboard with i3-8100). This system has built-in video only and no GPU card.

The error I saw on bootup was:

```
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: failed to add i915 component master (-19)
```

Further down I saw the following error twice:

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
```

The embedded i915 video appeared to work fine but no sound was being routed to the HDMI ports regardless of what ALSA or PulseAudio settings I used.

-19 is the kernel error code `ENODEV` ("no such device"), which appears several times in the snd_hda_intel driver code.

In order to support sound output over HDMI, video drivers for Linux register an "audio component" for the sound card driver (in my case Intel HD Audio a.k.a. `snd_hda_intel`) to connect to. Once this connection is made, the sound hardware can produce an audio stream for the GPU to multiplex onto the HDMI cable.

In my case, the i915 graphics driver was not registering this audio component with the kernel. This failure can happen at various stages of loading and initializing the i915 graphics driver. For me, it was due to the lack of availability of Kernel Mode Setting (KMS). The i915 driver requires KMS to operate properly and will not initialize and register the required audio components if it is not enabled.

I fixed this by adding the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf`:

`options i915 modeset=1`