# Intel HD Graphics 530 not working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm currently trying to setup an Ubuntu 15.10 to run VMs with VGAPassthrough. The to be dedicated graphics card should be my GTX750ti, with the internal graphics chip of the i7-6700k (Intel HD Graphics 530). But it simply won't work. I've done my research and learnt that the Skylake GPUs are kinda funky as they're pretty new.

**Symptoms:**

When checking with `sudo lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D` the only Graphics card shown is my 750ti

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 84ac
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

I've updated to kernel `4.3.4-040304-generic` and still same issue.

So far i

- tried kernel flag `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1` in kernel 4.2
- updated to kernel 4.3.4
- tried kernel flag `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` in kernel 4.3

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698168/cant-get-intel-hd-graphics-530-skylake-i7-6700-to-work)

**Update**
Still occuring with kernel `4.5.0-040500rc1-generic`

**Update 2**
When setting the CPU Graphics Card as primary display in BIOS, the monitor flickers a bit while loading the kernel, until the monitor turns completely black. Last error [before it turns black](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8bd814iepv1eoj/2016-01-26%2002.23.38.png)
Propably something related to bus speeds

**Update 3**
I reviewed the possible duplicate, but the iGPU doesn't get recognized:

```
[    2.382028] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: failed to add i915 component master (-19)
```

**Update 4**
Segfault in Xorg.0.log:

```
[    10.045] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 3840x1080
[    10.069] (EE) 
[    10.069] (EE) Backtrace:
[    10.069] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x555b106d668e]
[    10.069] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x555b10522000+0x1b89f9) [0x555b106da9f9]
[    10.069] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f26ad89b000+0x352f0) [0x7f26ad8d02f0]
[    10.069] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so (0x7f26a981b000+0xd74f) [0x7f26a982874f]
[    10.069] (EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (PixmapShareToSlave+0x8e) [0x555b1059694e]
[    10.069] (EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (RRCrtcSet+0x670) [0x555b1063b870]
[    10.069] (EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (ProcRRSetCrtcConfig+0x38b) [0x555b1063c89b]
[    10.069] (EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (0x555b10522000+0x5818f) [0x555b1057a18f]
[    10.069] (EE) 8: /usr/bin/X (0x555b10522000+0x5c34b) [0x555b1057e34b]
[    10.069] (EE) 9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f26ad8bba40]
[    10.069] (EE) 10: /usr/bin/X (_start+0x29) [0x555b105686c9]
[    10.069] (EE) 
[    10.069] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x8
[    10.069] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    10.069] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    10.069] (EE) 
[    10.069] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    10.069] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    10.069] (EE) 
[    10.070] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[    10.132] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Extract from syslog

```
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS dbus[723]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS gnome-session[1660]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS gnome-session[1660]: after 206 requests (206 known processed) with 10 events remaining.
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS gnome-session[1660]: (gnome-settings-daemon:1693): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0.
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1676]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1676]: after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1657]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS gnome-session[1660]: gnome-session[1660]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS gnome-session[1660]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS gnome-session[1660]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS gnome-session[1660]: gnome-session[1660]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS gdm[902]: GdmDisplay: display lasted 1,042746 seconds
Jan 27 11:17:35 JARVIS gdm[902]: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached: check X server log for errors
Jan 27 11:17:36 JARVIS acpid: client 1649[0:0] has disconnected
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skylake Integrated graphics not working on 15.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/725092/skylake-integrated-graphics-not-working-on-15-10)

Comment: Do you have any BIOS settings to use the iGPU rather than the discrete video card at boot time?

Comment: I set it to iGPU as the primary display, but the kernel crashes with some errors somewhat related to i915 or so...  gonna make a pic and link it
- Next thing i'll try is propably Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8bd814iepv1eoj/2016-01-26%2002.23.38.png

Comment: iGPU should work as primary display, the error looks like [bug #1501260](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1501260). You should [report a bug on freedesktop.org](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/how-report-bugs). There is also [a patch](https://patchwork.freedesktop.org/patch/60235/) that might fix the issue (if it does, mention that in the bug report).

Comment: `snd_hda_intel` - that's the audio driver, check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/694677/snd-hda-intel-0000001f-3-failed-to-add-i915-component-master-19) where the solution was apparently to uninstall the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Installed the intel drivers with the graphical installer from their site before trying the nightly builds, and it seems to work with igpu primary :) the card even gets recognized on the pci bus as a vga comptaible card, only problem left is that now xserver/gnome-shell won't startup

Comment: The last message is [ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.... -but nothing happens

Comment: Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` for errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34911/discussion-between-matze-and-bain).

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

It should work.