# Onboard HDMI audio stopped working after upgrade

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, hdmi

I rebooted this morning after upgrading packages, and the onboard HDMI output stopped working.

From /var/log/apt/history.log, these are all the packages installed/upgraded as part of unattended or manual upgrades between the last two reboots (2020-10-20 18:18:52 to 2020-10-25 17:57:58 Pacific/Auckland):

```
apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.9, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.10)
apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.9, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.10)
cryptsetup-bin:amd64 (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.2, 2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3)
cryptsetup-initramfs:amd64 (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.2, 2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3)
cryptsetup-run:amd64 (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.2, 2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3)
cryptsetup:amd64 (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.2, 2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3)
firefox-locale-en:amd64 (81.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 82.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
firefox:amd64 (81.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 82.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
libcryptsetup12:amd64 (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.2, 2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3)
libfreetype6:amd64 (2.10.1-2, 2.10.1-2ubuntu0.1)
libfreetype6:i386 (2.10.1-2, 2.10.1-2ubuntu0.1)
libnetplan0:amd64 (0.99-0ubuntu3~20.04.2, 0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.2)
linux-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.51.54, 5.4.0.52.55)
linux-headers-5.4.0-52-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-52.57, automatic)
linux-headers-5.4.0-52:amd64 (5.4.0-52.57, automatic)
linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.51.54, 5.4.0.52.55)
linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-52.57, automatic)
linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.51.54, 5.4.0.52.55)
linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-51.56, 5.4.0-52.57)
linux-modules-5.4.0-52-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-52.57, automatic)
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-52-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-52.57, automatic)
netplan.io:amd64 (0.99-0ubuntu3~20.04.2, 0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.2)
python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.9, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.10)
python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.9, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.10)
```

Based on that list it seems likely that the kernel update broke this functionality. `apt changelog linux-generic` just says "Bump ABI 5.4.0-52". A bit of searching found the [changelog](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_5.4.0-52.57/changelog), but the change seems to be only related to some Bluetooth CVEs.

[Similar issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1901117)

Motherboard:

```
$ sudo lshw -json | jq --raw-output '.[].children[] | select(.description == "Motherboard") | .vendor, .product'
ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.       
TUF B360-PRO GAMING (WI-FI)
```

---

What I've tried so far:

1. Verified that [multi-GPU support](https://askubuntu.com/a/747769/10371) is still enabled; that was how I finally got onboard HDMI audio to work in the first place.
2. [Set i915 modeset](https://askubuntu.com/a/1009183/10371) and rebooted.
3. Unplugged and re-plugged the HDMI cable in the motherboard slot. Nothing shows up in `journalctl --follow` because of either action.
4. Removed ~/.config/pavucontrol.ini and ~/.config/pulse.
5. Restarted PulseAudio using `pulseaudio -k`.
6. Rebooted into kernel release 5.4.0-51-generic.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1247850/10371) worked*! Step-by-step in case anyone who runs into this isn't familiar with the operations:

1. Edit /etc/default/grub as root.
2. On the line starting with "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=", remove the word "nomodeset".
3. Save & quit.
4. Run `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot

* Almost everything in that question is different, but the answer was so well researched I decided to just give it a try. I can't recall whether I set "nomodeset" myself at some point (and if so, why), but at least now there's a record.